# Fill the month for IsoWeek

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, isodate

Firstly, sorry for the long column, I had to post it all so you can better understand what I'm struggling with.

I have a calendar with TheDate and the ISOWeek.

What I'm trying to do is to create another column that represents the month of that date. The numbering will start with 1 and will have a full IsoWeek and a complete month.

For example, January will end on 2nd February because the last full week of Jan "bit" from February.
I tried a lot of solutions, like converting the ISOWeek to ISOMonth, but none gave the expected result.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:
Thanks to Alex below the solution is:

```
SELECT month(dateadd(d, 3, dateadd(WEEK, datediff(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(d,-1,'20200302')), 0)))
```

```
TheDate   IsoWeek  The Month---I want to add this 
12/30/2019  1       1
12/31/2019  1       1
1/1/2020    1       1
1/2/2020    1       1
1/3/2020    1       1
1/4/2020    1       1
1/5/2020    1       1
1/6/2020    2       1
1/7/2020    2       1
1/8/2020    2       1
1/9/2020    2       1
1/10/2020   2       1
1/11/2020   2       1
1/12/2020   2       1
1/13/2020   3       1
1/14/2020   3       1
1/15/2020   3       1
1/16/2020   3       1
1/17/2020   3       1
1/18/2020   3       1
1/19/2020   3       1
1/20/2020   4       1
1/21/2020   4       1
1/22/2020   4       1
1/23/2020   4       1
1/24/2020   4       1
1/25/2020   4       1
1/26/2020   4       1
1/27/2020   5       1
1/28/2020   5       1
1/29/2020   5       1
1/30/2020   5       1
1/31/2020   5       1
2/1/2020    5       1
2/2/2020    5       1
2/3/2020    6       2
2/4/2020    6       2
2/5/2020    6       2
2/6/2020    6       2
2/7/2020    6       2
2/8/2020    6       2
2/9/2020    6       2
2/10/2020   7       2
2/11/2020   7       2
2/12/2020   7       2
2/13/2020   7       2
2/14/2020   7       2
2/15/2020   7       2
2/16/2020   7       2
2/17/2020   8       2
2/18/2020   8       2
2/19/2020   8       2
2/20/2020   8       2
2/21/2020   8       2
2/22/2020   8       2
2/23/2020   8       2
2/24/2020   9       2
2/25/2020   9       2
2/26/2020   9       2
2/27/2020   9       2
2/28/2020   9       2
2/29/2020   9       2
3/1/2020    9       2
3/2/2020    10      3
3/3/2020    10      3
3/4/2020    10      3
3/5/2020    10      3
3/6/2020    10      3
3/7/2020    10      3
3/8/2020    10      3
3/9/2020    11      3
3/10/2020   11      3
3/11/2020   11      3
3/12/2020   11      3
3/13/2020   11      3
3/14/2020   11      3
3/15/2020   11      3
3/16/2020   12      3
3/17/2020   12      3
3/18/2020   12      3
3/19/2020   12      3
3/20/2020   12      3
3/21/2020   12      3
3/22/2020   12      3
3/23/2020   13      3
3/24/2020   13      3
3/25/2020   13      3
3/26/2020   13      3
3/27/2020   13      3
3/28/2020   13      3
3/29/2020   13      3
3/30/2020   14      3
3/31/2020   14      3
4/1/2020    14      3
4/2/2020    14      3
4/3/2020    14      3
4/4/2020    14      3
4/5/2020    14      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO weeks start on Mondays, therefore the month/year of a given week always equals the month/year on Thursday that week.
You can get this by week-truncating your date column, then add 3 days, like here:

```
ALTER TABLE calendar ADD TheMonth int;
UPDATE calendar SET TheMonth = month(dateadd(DAY, 3, dateadd(WEEK, datediff(WEEK, 0, TheDate), 0)))
```

EDIT: I've subtracted a day to work

```
SELECT month(dateadd(d, 3, dateadd(WEEK, datediff(WEEK, 0, dateadd(d,-1,TheDate)), 0)))
```

Comment: Hey, this works almost perfect. But if I run SELECT month(dateadd(d, 3, dateadd(WEEK, datediff(WEEK, 0, '20200202'), 0))) I get  2 instead of 1. I think this is related to the start of the week day. I SET DATEFIRST 1 but I get the same result :(

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is a valuable information when creating calendars.